# Laravel 5.4: Swift_TransportException connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to use the auth forgot password functionality but it's not working. I already turned on the access for less secure apps in gmail.

```
.env file
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

mail.php
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Comment: Try with different port and encryption
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the security settings on your Gmail account. 
Probably you need to set the allow less secure apps to access your account.
You can read here how to do it: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Also as an SMTP server use smtp.gmail.com